# Micronaut, db-scheduler: No current transaction present. Consider declaring @Transactional on the surrounding method

Tags: java, datasource, micronaut-data

I'm trying to use db-scheduler with Micronaut. Therefore, I created a @Singleton service where I inject the actual DataSource which is of type TransactionAwareDataSource. I then call a certain method to setup the scheduler which is something like:

```
  @Transactional
  public void createJob() {

    RecurringTask<Void> hourlyTask = Tasks.recurring("my-hourly-task", FixedDelay.ofHours(1))
        .execute((inst, ctx) -> {
          System.out.println("Executed!");
        });

    final Scheduler scheduler = Scheduler
        .create(dataSource)
        .startTasks(hourlyTask)
        .threads(5)
        .build();

    scheduler.start();
  }
```

which, at "create" throws this exception:

```
io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.NoTransactionException: No current transaction present. Consider declaring @Transactional on the surrounding method
    at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.java:65)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:96)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnection$Intercepted.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.kagkarlsson.scheduler.jdbc.AutodetectJdbcCustomization.<init>(AutodetectJdbcCustomization.java:40)
    at com.github.kagkarlsson.scheduler.SchedulerBuilder.lambda$build$0(SchedulerBuilder.java:190)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
```

Everywhere else in my app everything is working like it should, means, I can read and write to the DB via the repositories and @Transactional is working as well.

I'm not 100% sure where the problem is, but I guess it does have to do with placing the annotation. Which - in this case - is nothing I can really change. On the other hand, if I create the datasource manually, effectively bypassing micronaut, it's working.

BTW: the exception comes up within db-scheduler where the first call to the DB is made (c.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName()).

Micronaut-Version: 2.3.4, Micronaut-Data: 2.2.4, everything setup properly.

Do you guys have any ideas how to solve this problem? Or is it even a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about this exception, but there is already a way provided by Micronaut to create a scheduled task. Please have a look at the example below: https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-scheduled/guide/index.html

Comment: @AmitB10 Thanks, for your answer. Yes, I knew about the scheduling options of micronaut and I did read the example already, to which you pointed to. But my needs are far more than the micronaut scheduler can offer: Persistant jobs, rescheduling, starting, stopping, and so on. Probably I go with quartz anyway.

Comment: @ChristianSpiewok, did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I am having the same type of issue using another library that runs a background job reading from a database using the EntityManager.

Comment: I run into a same issue with using JobRunnr library, and the exception is also at `connection.getMetaData()`

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that Micronaut Data wraps the `DataSource` into a `TransactionAwareDataSource`, as you mentioned. Your library `db-scheduler` or mine `JobRunr` picks it up, and operates without the required annotations. The solution is to unwrap it before giving it to the `db-scheduler` or `JobRunr`:

Kotlin:

```kotlin
val unwrappedDataSource = (dataSource as DelegatingDataSource).targetDataSource
```

Java:

```java
DataSource unwrappedDataSource = ((DelegatingDataSource) dataSource).targetDataSource
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked better for me than the existing answer. See below for explanation. The example is in Kotlin but it naturally translates to Java.

**Note:** The example is for Micronaut v3.

```kotlin
@Factory
internal class DbSchedulerFactory(
    private val dataSource: DataSource,
) {

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    @Singleton
    fun scheduler(): Scheduler {
        return Scheduler.create(configureDataSource(dataSource), tasks)
            .threads(10)
            // ...
            .build()
    }

    private fun configureDataSource(dataSource: DataSource): DataSource {
        // Is transaction-aware DataSource proxy active? (Note: class is private so we match by name)
        return if (dataSource::class.qualifiedName == "io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionAwareDataSource.DataSourceProxy") {
            log.info("Adding support for out-of-transaction connection fetching since the data source is a TransactionAwareDataSource")
            object : DelegatingDataSource(dataSource) {
                override fun getConnection() =
                    if (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()) dataSource.connection
                    else DelegatingDataSource.unwrapDataSource(dataSource).connection
            }
        } else {
            dataSource
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation

After (too) many hours of debugging and searching, I found [this issue](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/1293) basically stating that: if a) you use Micronaut's default transaction handling and b) you have a code that will fetch and interact with a `Connection` from a transaction-aware `DataSource`, then you will get the `NoTransactionException` exception unless the interaction with the connection happens within transaction scope (either with `@Transactional` or [programmatic transactions](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/snapshot/guide/#programmaticTransactions)).

X.Y.'s solution gets rid of the exception by getting connections straight from the *underlying* data source (bypassing transaction-aware `DataSource` proxy), which typically will be a connection pool like Hikari. However, in doing so, it doesn't support db-scheduler participating in Micronaut's transaction scope.

This was a deal breaker for me, since I wanted `scheduler.schedule`, `scheduler.reschedule`, `scheduler.cancel` (and all the other advanced features like custom tasks with `CompletionHandler`s) participate in `@Transaction` scope. At the same time I didn't want plain db-scheduler code to be concerned with transaction scopes.

Slapping `@Transactional` or programmatic transactions everywhere isn't a viable solution as you don't always control the code interacting with `Connection`s (and this is what db-scheduler does when: building the `Scheduler`, starting it, and during it's operation).

Possibly, I could switch to Spring-based transaction handling (described in the Tip at the end of [this section](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/snapshot/guide/#transactions)) but this would pull a lot of other stuff I didn't want.

Instead, I wrote the above: a wrapper around the transaction-aware `DataSource` proxy (yes, wrapper for a wrapper) that:

1. Returns the connection bound to current transaction scope, if there is one.
2. Returns a connection from the underlying data source, if there isn't a transaction scope.