# Get Connection from injected DataSource throws exception with multiple datasources in Micronaut Data JDBC

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

Couldn't get connection from injected DataSource like spring and as written in documentation(*Configuring Multiple Data Sources*) [https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-sql/latest/guide/#:~:text=Configuring%20Multiple%20Data%20Sources](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-sql/latest/guide/#:%7E:text=Configuring%20Multiple%20Data%20Sources) throws

```console
Suppressed: io.micronaut.transaction.exceptions.NoTransactionException: No current transaction present. Consider declaring @Transactional on the surrounding method
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.java:65)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnection$Intercepted.close(Unknown Source)
        at com.demo.service.DemoService.processRecords(DemoService.java:116)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
    Caused by: io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.exceptions.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: No current JDBC Connection found. Consider wrapping this call in transactional boundaries.
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:135)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:93)
        at io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionalConnectionInterceptor.java:63)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by unwrapping injected DataSource ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472191/micronaut-db-scheduler-no-current-transaction-present-consider-declaring-tra)):

```java
DataSource db1Ds = ((DelegatingDataSource) db1DataSource).getTargetDataSource();
Connection db1Conn = db1Ds.getConnection();
/* or
Connection db1Conn = ((DelegatingDataSource) db1DataSource).getConnection();
*/
```

I don't know that there is short solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (if it's possible) you can just add `@Transactional` annotation on the method, as exception suggests